# How to encode properly the plus sign (+) when making a request with webflux webclient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am trying to send an international formatted phone number using spring Webflux Webclient and to read this phone number via another application also using webflux.

My code looks like this :

```
webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build();

return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .path("/endpoint")
                    .queryParam("phone-number", "+33612345678")
                    .build()
            )
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Unfortunately, somewhere between this call and the receiver, the plus sign is replaced by a space.
The endpoint receives : " 33612345678" as a String.

The netty debug log of the request shows this :

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 47 45 54 20 2f 63 75 73 74 6f 6d 65 72 73 3f 70 |GET  /endpoint?p|
|00000010| 68 6f 6e 65 2d 6e 75 6d 62 65 72 3d 2b 33 33 36 |hone-number=+336|
|00000020| 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 26 6f 6e 6c 79 2d 72 65 |12345678
```

I tried to encode the phone-number by myself like this :

```
.queryParam("phone-number", UriUtils.encode("+34612345678", StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

And netty's log shows :

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 47 45 54 20 2f 63 75 73 74 6f 6d 65 72 73 3f 70 |GET  /endpoint?p|
|00000010| 68 6f 6e 65 2d 6e 75 6d 62 65 72 3d 25 32 35 32 |hone-number=%252|
|00000020| 42 33 34 36 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 20 48 54 54 |B34612345678 HTT|
```

It seems that the phone number has been encoded twice.

+ -> %2B -> %252B

the plus sign has been encoded by `UriUtils.encode` then uriBuilder has encoded the %.

The only way I found to make it work is by disabling the encoding of the UriBuilder :

```
 DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(baseUrl);
    factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
    this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .uriBuilderFactory(factory)
            .build();
```

and having my custom encoding `UriUtils.encode("+34612345678", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

in which case the netty's logs looks like expected :

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 47 45 54 20 2f 63 75 73 74 6f 6d 65 72 73 3f 70 |GET  /endpoint?p|
|00000010| 68 6f 6e 65 2d 6e 75 6d 62 65 72 3d 25 32 42 33 |hone-number=%2B3|
|00000020| 34 36 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 20 48 54 54 50 2f |4612345678 HTTP/|
```

And of course, the endpoint receiving the phone number get : "+33612345678"

To sum it up, it looks like the UriBuilder is encoding certain sign like "%" but does not encode the "+" sign.
Spring reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web-uri-encoding

Comment: that is correct, plus sign is not encoded as per RFC 3986 it is mentioned in the spring docs for `queryparam` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriBuilder.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...- You can enforce a stricter encoding using a template https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web-uri-encoding

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the `queryparam` docs.

I tried to enforce that stricter encoding but I don't get it.
It says that the `TEMPLATE_AND_VALUES`: Uses `UriComponentsBuilder#encode()` and that the `UriComponentsBuilder#encode(): Pre-encodes` the URI template first and then strictly encodes URI variables when expanded.

An example is given with the ";" character : The first option replaces ";" with "%3B" in URI variables.

That is what I did by forcing the 
`factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.TEMPLATE_AND_VALUES);`

But it doesn't encode ";" nor "+"

Comment: try out using the `VALUES_ONLY` encoding

Comment: I tried them all but none of them encodes that ; or + sign :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I struggled with same issue but found a workaround from the [Spring reference you linked](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web-uri-encoding).

This should work for you:

```java
return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uriBuilder.build())
                    .path("/endpoint")
                    .queryParam("phone-number", "{phone-number}")
                    .encode()
                    .buildAndExpand("+33612345678")
                    .toUri()
            )
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot test it because we completely removed spring webflux from our projects !
I'll mark it as the right answer until someone prove me wrong :)

Comment: You can use directly uriBuilder.queryParam....build("+33612345678") without using UriComponentsBuilder :) 
However it doesn't work if you have an array of phone numbers. See my comment on the other answer

Answer (score 1):

A solution provided [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21399#issuecomment-453472277), you can try this way

```java
DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
URI uri = factory.uriString("https://spring.io/")
            .queryParam("query", "{query}")
            .build("spring+framework"); 
// http://spring.io/?query=spring%2Bframework
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it in my Kotlin application using:

```kotlin
webClient.get()
    .uri { uriBuilder ->
        val queryParams = mapOf(
            "phone-number" to "+33612345678",
            "mobile-number" to "+61432111222"
        )
        uriBuilder.path("/endpoint")
            .apply { 
                queryParams.keys.forEach { key ->
                    queryParam(key, "{$key}")
                }
            }
            .build(queryParams)
    }
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono<String>()
```

Comment: This works if it's a single query param value. If it's an array of values, passing it through the build method will encode it as a list rather. eg : `phone-number=[+33612345678,+33612345677]` rather than `phone-number=+33612345678&phone-number=+33612345677`